# Want to send e-mail and get thankyou page through PHP. But $HEADER and $HEADERS not working together

Tags: php

This is the PHP code that i am using for the form. I want to append it with $headers and want it to redirect to thankyou page when form is submitted. I am getting thankyou page but not receiving the e-mail.

```
<?php

$action = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $e_mail = $_POST['e_mail'];
    $service = $_POST['service'];
    $maker = $_POST['maker'];
    $model = $_POST['model'];
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

$to = 'reckless.sam@gmail.com';
$headers = 'From: Micheal Key <reply@locallockman.com>';
$subject = 'Customer Service Request';
$body = 'Customer name: ' . $fname .  "\n" .  
'Contact-No: ' . $phone .  "\n" . 
'E-mail: ' . $e_mail .  "\n" .
'Service-Type: ' . $service .  "\n" .  
'Car-Make: '. $maker .  "\n" . 
'Car-Model: ' . $model .  "\n" . 
'Model-Year: ' . $year .  "\n" . 
'Service Required: ' . $message .  "\n" ;
$thankyou = "thankyou.html"; // thank you page
if(isset($_POST['fname']) && isset($_POST['phone']) && isset($_POST['e_mail']) && isset($_POST['service']) && isset($_POST['message']))

$maker = $model = $year = 'Not Set'; // Or just use a empty string: '';
if(isset($_POST['maker'])){
    $maker = $_POST['maker'];
}
if(isset($_POST['model'])){
    $model = $_POST['model'];
}
if(isset($_POST['year'])){
    $year = $_POST['year'];
}{
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $e_mail = $_POST['e_mail'];
    $type = $_POST['service'];
    $maker = $_POST['maker'];

    $model = $_POST['model'];

    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    if(empty($phone)){
        echo 'Fields With * Sign Are Mandatory';
    }
    else{
        if(mail($to,$headers,$subject,$body,$headers)){
     header("Location: $thankyou");
?>
<script>location.replace('<?php echo $thankyou;?>')</script>
<?
        }
        else{
            echo 'There was an error sending email/s.';
        }
    }

}


?>
```

I will be waiting for your answers.Please let me know if you would like to know anything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Couple of things.. a) Is this in windows?  If so, that is most likely your problem. b) have you checked spam/trash folders? ^^  Also, look at how the [`mail`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function's parameters. ^^

Comment: Do you setup your own email on localhost server or use remote one?

Answer (score 2):

just use this there is no need for `<script>`

```
if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)){
    header("Location: $thankyou");
}
```

Comment: Their redirect is fine ;)  (Granted, it is bloated, but not causing the particular issue they are asking about.) ^^

Comment: @Sam you have `$headers` two times as well ;)

Comment: if i remove the $headers = 'From: name<abc>; then it is received in spam. But i want to receive the e-mail in inbox.

Comment: Oh yeah Jon! I made that mistake. One is only $header i.e. for redirecting to another page and another is $headers to get a header and receive it in inbox.

Comment: @Jon ohh thanks, I never noticed **Sam** has used two times $headers.

Comment: @sam Ahh, then look at the mail function to properly set up for sending, as I don't know what you are doing when you get it properly, but if you get it as spam, then how you call function is probably off. =]  And no worries Yogesh, I didn't realize he had it twice until I saw your code either lol.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar i made that mistake. Can you please tell me what should be changed?

Comment: +1 for your edited answer - damn you for posting first. :P lol

Comment: @Jon let me tell you clearly. With this code, after submitting the page is redirected to thankyou page, but i do not get the e-mail.

But if i remove the 

$header = 'From: Micheal Key<reply@locallockman.com>'; 

code then e-mail is received,but in spam. I want my page to be redirected and also want that $headers on the e-mail, so that it should get in the inbox. I hope you get it this time.

Comment: @yogesh getting this error

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/33/8387133/html/blog.php:8) in /home/content/33/8387133/html/blog.php on line 143

E-mail received in spam and wasn't redirected to Thankyou page.

Comment: write `exit();` after `header();`.

Comment: to add to @YogeshSuthar, look through the code prior to that and make sure nothing has been `echo`'d or anything before that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [`mail`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function.  Then, change your mail code to:

```
mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)
```

If you still don't get mail, it's most likely an issue of being in windows, which has various ways to solve, but can easily be found. ^^

Comment: Jon i think the problem is because of $headers and $header. With that code e-mail will be sent but i am not redirected to thankyou page. I want to get on thankyou page when submit button is pressed.

Comment: The error that you said you got is when it went to redirect you. `$header` is not defined, but you would get the `headers already sent` error if there has been output prior to that call.

Comment: still not working... :(.. Not getting thankyou page and getting that code error.